# else if looping quandry

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement

I am in the second phase of a project where I need to extend my program into a menu driven application to query the database I have on a .txt file. So, my trouble is that I cannot get my loop to be perpetual. It always terminates when it initializes from one option to the next. Here is the snippet of my code that is my int main:

```
    int main ()
{
        char Q,q;
        char S,s;
        char task;
        string pathname;
        string z;
        int count=0;
        cout << "Welcome to Jason Rodriguez's Library Database." << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the name of the backup file: ";
        cin >> pathname;
        ifstream inFile(pathname.c_str());
        while(!inFile.eof())
        {
            getline(inFile,z);
            count++;
        }

    while (task != 'Q' || task != 'q') {

        cout << count << " records loaded successfully." << endl;
        cout << "Enter Q to (Q)uit, Search (A)uthor, Search (T)itle, (S)how All: ";
        cin >> task;
        if ((task == 'Q')||(task =='q'))
        {
            cout << "Program will now terminate";
            break;
        }
        else if ((task == 'S')||(task =='s'))
        {
            showAll (loadData (pathname));
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Enter Q to (Q)uit, Search (A)uthor, Search (T)itle, (S)how All: ";
            cin >> task;
        }

    }
}
```

I need to add two more options into the loop on top of these two but I figured I should get the first two working correctly first. The other two should be plug & chug after that. Basically what I was trying to do is say if the user enters Q or q, terminate the program. Else, if user hits S or s, activate showall function and after ward, go back to the original query. It isn't working though. Assistance is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a loop here. Is this code inside of a loop in your real code? If so, remove the `return 0`.

Comment: I know I don't have a loop. That is my quandry. I am trying to create one in this situation but I don't know where I am going wrong. I took the return 0 away but it did not do anything at all

Comment: Uh, what does that last `}` close? My syntax checker is going crazy...

Comment: You're loop sure looks perpetual to me.  The condition in the second `while` is always true.  (The first `while` is wrong as well.  You never loop on `inFile.eof()`.)

Comment: Your outer `||` should be `&&`. (All characters are inequal to either 'q' or 'Q'.)

Comment: @james, the infile part works just fine. The second while is not  responding to q , it only responds to s.

Comment: @moldbdnilo I tried it both ways but it is not responding to q, it only responds to s.

Comment: @tjameson the } isn't a concern, I can delete or add a close bracket. The goal here is to find out why the while loop is not responding as a loop. It does not respond to q. It only responds to s.

Comment: @Jason The `inFile` part works because you never use the value you've input.  If you try to do so, it's broken.

Answer (score 0):

**Menus almost always require loops** - *especially* ones that require the user to enter the correct choice input. The most applicable one in a case like this is the while loop - but essentially, any other loop variant can be used.

UPDATE:

```
int main ()
{
    char task;//this is the only char needed. Your other chars were redundant
    string pathname;
    string temp;//I changed z to temp to better reflect its purpose
    int count=0;

    cout << "Welcome to Jason Rodriguez's Library Database." << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the name of the backup file: ";
    cin >> pathname;

    ifstream inFile(pathname.c_str());//this is potentially a problem in that you aren't verifying that the pathname is a valid one

    //you did not check to see that your file was open, otherwise there is no way to tell that you successfully opened the file
    if (inFile.is_open()) {
        //while(!inFile.eof()) is a character by character read and comparison
        //made your life easier by shortening it down to this - which ensures
        //that a line is read. (Much faster and more readable)
        while(getline(inFile,temp)) 
        {
            count++;
        }
        inFile.close();//always close a file after you've used it

        //At this point the entire file has been read. So, this is where this message SHOULD be 
        cout << count << " records loaded successfully." << endl;
    }
    else {
        //if there was an error opening the file (i.e. wrong path, or it simply does not exist), this will be displayed
        cout << "There was a problem opening your file" << endl;
        exit(0);//and the program will terminate
    }

    while (task != 'Q' || task != 'q') {
        cout << "Enter Q to (Q)uit, Search (A)uthor, Search (T)itle, (S)how All: ";
        cin >> task;
        if ((task == 'Q')||(task =='q'))
        {
            cout << "Program will now terminate";
            break;
        }
        else if ((task == 'S')||(task =='s'))
        {
            string author;
            //showAll (loadData (pathname));
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Search an Author" << endl;
            cin >> author;//get the author name to search from the user

            //write code to search an author here
        }
    }
}
```

There are a number of issues with the code that you posted which I will forgo for the sake of brevity. Hence, note the following:

**Your code was printing the same message per option (except for quit).** Of course it would appear that it didn't work. Each option is a different task. Print what each task does (similar to what I did).

1. You wish to search the file for an author, but you have not stored it. Look into a way of storing it that appeases your instructor.
2. It would be ideal for you to use `switch` in this case, considering the increasing complexity of your code.
3. Try breaking down each task into functions, and call them to make your main function readable. In fact, it is a good programming practice for your main function to be as small as possible.

And, as juanchopanza quite rightly pointed out: you have some fundamental issues with C++. Try doing some more exercises and do more examples from a good C++ book.

Comment: Bingo, thanks for that. I've been staring at this screen too long and missed that option. I think I will take a walk tothe store, get some fresh air, and finish this bad boy up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: *this screen meaning my xcode window, not this site's page haha

Comment: I spoke too soon. This solution does not work. I hit a snag. I will edit my post to show my whole int main() so you can see what I mean.

Comment: The solution doesn't work because you posted _part_ of the problem and not the _whole_ thing. That being said, I have edited my original post to answer your updated question, @Jason.